# Using the definition of limit to prove one

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, definition

I have doubts to prove that $lim_{x\to1} (2x-1) = 1$ with the definition of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. I have operated but I do not know how to go on.

$|(2x-1)-(1)|=|2x-2|$

We select $\delta=\epsilon$

$0<|2x-2|<\epsilon$

I checked other answers already posted in the web, but I do not understand this last step. How do you know that inequality is true? And how do I continue proving the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just factor out the $2$ to get $$|2x-2|=2|x-1|<2\delta.$$
Set $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{2} $ and you are done.

What you found with $\delta = \epsilon $ can obviously not work because in the definition of this limit it says $|x-1|<\delta $ which is why you would only get $|2x-2|<2\epsilon $ by setting $\delta=\epsilon $.

Comment: Why do you set  $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$? That's the part I get lost because I do not get why that proves that the limit is 1 @mxian

Comment: The definition is that the limit is $1$ iff for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that all $x $ with $|x-1|<\delta $ fulfil $|(2x-1)-1|<\epsilon $. So by choosing $\delta =\frac {\epsilon}{2} $ and then proving that $|(2x-1)-1|<\epsilon $ follows from $|x-1|<\delta $ we have shown that your limit is indeed $1$. So in fact, our choice of $\delta $ can be completely arbitrary as long as it works for our proof. In this case $\frac {\epsilon}{3},  \frac {\epsilon}{4}, \frac {\epsilon}{5} $ etc. would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

We need $$|2x-1-1|<\epsilon$$ or
$$|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Thus, for all $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$0<|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Rightarrow|2x-1-1|<\epsilon,$$
which says that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(2x-1)=1$$
by the definition of the limit.